# Angular ng-class re-evaulate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

Im using ng-class to apply the class active when collapseSidebar is set to true revealing my sidebar.

```
<div class="row full-height row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left" ng-class="{active: collapseSidebar}">
    <div id="sidebar" class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 sidebar-offcanvas">
    </div>
```

js

```
$scope.collapseSidebar = false;

    $scope.select = function(thing)
    {
        $scope.selectedThing = (thing !== $scope.selectedThing) ? thing : null;
        $scope.collapseSidebar = true;
    };
```

However the sidebar can be hidden in other ways (click a menu icon in the top left) removing the class active. When I call select(thing) I was hoping that ng-class would be re-evaluated and the class 'active' would be re-applied, however this does not happen, I have tried setting it to false and then straight back to true which also didn't work.

How can I get ng-class to re-evaluate collapseSidebar and apply 'active' even if the value is the same as be

Comment: Can you provide your code where the select function gets called?

Comment: Full fiddle would be appreciated - without live case tracing your problem can be nigh-impossible. That aside, key part seems to be this: "(...)However the sidebar can be hidden in other ways (...) removing the class active". Most likely, whatever way you're removing this class is un-Angularish (so to speak) - as in: not triggering Angular digest cycle, therefore not causing it to re-evaluate (update) everything in your view. This is quite common when using jQuery with Angular - http://tech.zumba.com/2014/08/02/angularjs-forget-jquery/ . Focus especially on section titled "Indigestion".

Comment: "Most likely, whatever way you're removing this class is un-Angularish (so to speak)" That is correct, it's using jQuery, however at that point I don't expect angular to re-evaluate. But when $scope.select() is called later on it does not re-add the class, perhaps because active is removed outside of angular it's under the impression that 'active' should already be there?

Comment: The most obvious answer would be to always remove/add this class by setting `$scope.collapseSidebar` (`ng-click` to function doing just that?), *never* by manual DOM manipulation. It has its place, but 9 times out of 10 it is Pandora's box when working with Angular. Not much more I can say without live example.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
ng-class="{'active': collapseSidebar}"
```

(The active class name is wrapped by the "'" characters)